# adding CloudWatch to a stack with CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

I am currently in charge of adding CloudWatch integration to an already made Cloud Formation stack.

We create the stacks through CLI, but at the moment we add CloudWatch manually afterwards.

What i need is to automatically activate CloudWatch for instances and monitor CPU, hdd and so on through the use of CloudFormation templates.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that you don't add new CloudWatch items to the existing CloudFormation stack. Instead, create a CF template with the appropriate metrics and deploy from this template for each instance you want to monitor.

From there, I suggest you create an AWS Lambda function that will receive an Instance Id as input and will deploy a CloudFormation stack against the instance. You should enable CloudTrail on your account and create a Rule to match any `RunInstances` event on the account and trigger the Lambda function.

Keep in mind the [default limit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cloudformation-limits.html) for CloudFormation stacks is 200. You might need to request an increase depending on your use case.

Comment: I created the metric templates and the alarms and i want to integrate them with OPSGenie with CloudWatch. Can you please provide more details on how to do that?